# JSF dynamic navigation

Tags: java, jsf-2, navigation, el

I have some problem with JSF dynamic navigation. I'm using JSF 2.2 version. I'm trying to organize dynamic navigation

```
<h:commandButton value="Enter" action="loginController.result">
```

LoginController.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String result(){
    return "register";
}

}
```

And it doesn't work. When I try to go to needed page it writes:" Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/index.xhtml' for action 'loginController.result' with outcome 'loginController.result'".  I tryed to return "register.xhtml","\register.xhtml","\register" etc. But it didn't work too. When I write:

```
<h:commandButton value="Enter" action="register">
```

It is working as it should.
I know what the way to make it working exists. Please, help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an EL expression so JSF will invoke your JSF bean method:

```
<h:commandButton value="Enter" action="#{loginController.result}">
```

Otherwise the value of the `action` attribute would be interpreted as a string literal, that's why you see it *working* when you use `action="register"`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It has helped me